# How to display a document picker dialog - Alfresco 6

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco 6.0.1. I've created a user dashlet, and I want to add a button, which when clicked displays a dialog which allows the user to pick a document from the site document library.

There's a form control [here](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/DocumentPicker.html), but no guidance on how to use it.

I suppose I could use a form to do this. But my preference is for a button, to trigger the display of a document picker dialog.

I've searched the web for a suitable example, but unfortunately not turned up anything useful.
Looking for links to a relevant example, or other guidance.

Ok as requested, here's my dashlet. It's a Freemarker template, for use with Alfresco. I wish to display the document picker when the 'Upload' button is clicked.

```
<#-- Use Alfresco's FormUI for editing Meetings -->
<#include "../../../../org/alfresco/components/form/form.dependencies.inc">

<@markup id="css">
  <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="${url.context}/res/components/dashlets/management-information.css" 
    group="dashlets"/>
  </@>
<@markup id="js">
<@script src="${url.context}/res/components/dashlets/fbs-utils.js"/>
<@script src="${url.context}/res/components/dashlets/management-information- 
  operator.js"/>
<@script src="${url.context}/res/components/dashlets/management-information- 
  upload.js"/>
</@>

<@markup id="html">
<@uniqueIdDiv>
  <#assign id = args.htmlid?html>
  <#assign dashboardconfig=config.scoped['Dashboard']['dashboard']>

  <div class="dashlet fbs-mi-list">
    <div class="title">
      <#if siteId??>
        ${msg("title.fbs.meetings.associated")}
      <#else>
        ${msg("title.fbs.management-information.all")}
      </#if>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar flat-button">
      <div class="align-left">
        <span class="yui-button yui-push-button" >
          <span class="first-child">
            <button id="createMeeting"
              title="Upload Management Information"
              onclick="FBS.util.uploadMI()">Upload...
            </button>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="align-right">
      <#if user.isAdmin >
        <span class="container">
          <input type="checkbox" id="${id}-toggleDeletedmi"
            class="toggleDeleted"/>
          <label for="${id}-toggleDeletedmi"
            title="${msg("deleted.tip")}">${msg("deleted.label")}</label>
        </span>
      </#if>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body scrollableList" <#if args.height??>style="height: 
   ${args.height?html}px;"</#if>>
    <table class="mi">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not really the place to seek recommendations in this manner

Comment: Mark I'm looking for advice on how to achieve this with Alfresco. It's not a recommendation for anything. I'm looking for technical advice.

Comment: Advice, recommendations, do search for you are all off topic for this coding site.  Try some code, then put it in your question and why/what issues you face, then you can get the right track here.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is not appropriate. I'm looking for code examples of how to do this.

Comment: It is not really MY thought but the site guidelines.  "I've created a user dashlet" ok so put THAT code in here, then detail where your issue lies

Comment: Again, looking for a code example of how to do this.

Comment: Ok, code attached as requested. I would appreciate you reverting your downvote. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199405/discussion-between-andrew-fielden-and-mark-schultheiss).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. After digging around in the Alfresco source, I found a document picker control widget called picker.ftl.

You can use this in a form, with the following code

```
<config>
<forms>
  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>
  <form id="uploadMIForm">
    <field-visibility>
      <show id="srcNode" />
    </field-visibility>
    <appearance>
      <field id="srcNode" label-id="prop.search.cm_search_in_folder" >
          <control template="controls/mycomponent/picker.ftl">
              <control-param name="startLocation">{doclib}</control-param>
          </control>
      </field>
    </appearance>
  </form>
</forms>
</config>
```